# How can I change the properties of an instantiated gameObject in game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have a spawner which instantiates a `gameObject` multiple times (the game it's like a runner). Now this `gameObject` has a script which has `void Start()` and in the void start it has a function that makes the gameobject to take a random color. Every time I run the game and the first prefab takes a color (ex. green) and then the second one takes another color (ex. red) - but this first object takes the color of the second, like it has the void start multiple times. How to fix that?

Comment: Please provide some code samples and try to format your question in a more readable way.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simple `static` counter like e.g.

```
private static Color[] colors = new []{ 
    Color.green, 
    Color.red, 
    Color.blue, 
    Color.yellow, 
    Color.black 
};

private static int index = 0;

private void Start()
{
    if(index => colors.Length)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Not enough colors!", this);
        return;
    }

    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[index]; 
    index++;
}
```

Or if you want it random as you say you could do e.g.

```
private static Color[] colors = new []{ 
    Color.green, 
    Color.red, 
    Color.blue, 
    Color.yellow, 
    Color.black 
};

private static int index = 0;

private void Start()
{
    if(index => colors.Length)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Not enough colors!", this);
        return;
    }

    if(index == 0)
    {
        // the first time shuffle up the array
        var rnd = new Random();
        colors = colors.OrderBy((c) => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
    }

    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[index]; 
    index++;
}
```

Or if you really want it completely random you could simply do (might have multiple "equal" or very similar results though)

```
private void Start()
{
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = GetCompletelyRandomColor();
}

private static Color GetCompletelyRandomColor()
{
    var r = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    var g = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    var b = Random.Range(0f, 1f);

    return new Color(r, g, b);
}
```